# Is it possible to find the infinite Sum using telescopic way?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find the value of $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^n {\frac{2^{-i}}{1+2^{2^{-i}}}}$$
This is from 2022 ICMC Round 2 competition,
I was thinking about it as a telescopic series which I`m unable to convert can someone please help how to solve this one. Thanks in advance

Comment: Empirically it seems to be about $0.442695$ or $\frac1{\log_e(2)}-1$